# Install Boost headers to specific directory (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, boost, installation

I've downloaded, extracted, and compiled the Boost libraries (including the separately compiled libraries). I've used their install procedure a couple times now but I can't seem to get it to do exactly what I want. Right now, when I install Boost after compiling it goes to

```
C:\Boost
```

This is fine. The compiled libs go to

```
C:\Boost\lib
```

which is also fine. The problem I have is with the installation of the precompiled headers. They got put at

```
C:\Boost\include\boost-1_54\boost
```

Is there a way to use the Boost build system and install tools to set the precompiled headers to be installed to just

```
C:\Boost\include
```

and not have the Boost version number be a part of that folder hierarchy?

I don't plan on using multiple versions of Boost at the same time so I don't have a use for actually having that version number. I realize I could move them manually after the install is complete, but I wanted to see first if I've overlooked or misunderstood something about Boost's build system.

Comment: What commands do you invoke when building boost? What "precompiled headers" do you mean?

Comment: I ran `bootstrap` and then `.\b2 -j8 --prefix=C:\Boost --libdir=C:\Boost\lib --includedir=C:\Boost\include install`. The precompiled headers are the hpp files that don't require compilation to be used, the files that go in the include directory.

Comment: I see. What do you get if you add  `--layout=system`?

Comment: So that got me closer. In order to use `--layout=system` I also had to specify which variant I was building (I decided to default to release for now) in order to prevent filename clashing on the libs. The problem is the include directory still looks like `C:\Boost\include\boost\[all hpp files]`. Is there any way to get rid of that second "boost" in the path?

**EDIT** Sorry, I just realized I mistyped one of the options on the prompt. I'll try one more time.

**EDIT 2** Ok, I've fixed the command line issue but it's still adding that second Boost in the path.

Comment: Well, with `Boost.Build` you can do virtually anything, but this going to be not so trivial. I guess you'll have to customize your target using `user-config.jam` file (http://www.boost.org/doc/display_build.php/boost-build/boost-build/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/installing.html). Besides, try posting to boost-users ML.

Comment: this question has a potential to become a reference question IMHO. I would be expecting GURUs  here.

Answer (score 1):

`--layout=system` removes the versioned subdirectory from the include path (as @IgorR. pointed out).

"Removing that second boost in the path" is a bad idea. In a respectable OS (*cough...*), the include files for various libraries are supposed to co-exist in one common include directory, hence the `boost` subdirectory to avoid clashes. Boost headers are therefore habitually referred to as e.g. `#include <boost/any.hpp>`, i.e. *including* that `boost/` subdirectory.

This is done both by third-party software using Boost, and by Boost itself. If you remove the second `boost` from the path, you would end up with `C:\Boost\include\any.hpp`, and any Boost-using software won't compile as not even Boost could find its own includes.

Comment: I know this question is ancient, but it looked so lonely without answer...

Comment: `--layout=system` fails build when I compile both debug|release versions... Still looking for an answer.

Comment: Try `--layout=tagged`. It removes extra version subfolder, but generates lib names like `libboost_system-mt-x64.lib` to avoid name clashing.